# Shiny plot not displaying data

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a shiny app to show COVID-19 cases for the 10 worst affected countries with refreshes daily from the ECDC website. I want to be able to limit cases and deaths using slider inputs, and select date periods with date inputs, (all already added).
The code is below, but when I run the app I get a blank plot, the axis are displaying correctly but I can't get the points to appear. This should be able to run on any computer as the code just downloads the data set from the ECDC page.
Any solutions?

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), ".xlsx", sep = "")

GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))

data <- read_excel(tf)

include<-c("United_Kingdom","Italy","France","China",
           "United_States_of_America","Spain","Germany",
           "Iran","South_Korea","Switzerland")
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("COVID-19 Daily Confirmed Cases & Deaths"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("Country", "Select Country", selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,
                         width = NULL),
            dateRangeInput("DateRep","Select Date Range", start = "2019-12-31", end = NULL),
            sliderInput("Cases","Select Cases Range", min = 1, max = 20000, value = NULL),
            sliderInput("Deaths", "Select Death Range", min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
            submitButton("Refresh")


        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$plot <- renderPlot({

        include<-input$Country

        plot_data<-filter(data, `Countries and territories` %in% include)%>%
            filter(between(input$Cases))

        plot_data%>% ggplot(aes(x=input$DateRep, y=input$Cases, size =input$Deaths, color = input$Country)) +
            geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
            theme_light()

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: can you add a `print(head(plot_data))` to see if you are getting any data to the plotting function? output will be in the console while you are running the app

Comment: is this in the console or the shiny script? If in the console the data is printed, and if I add it to the script just above ```shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)``` it is also printed correctly

Comment: So your data is being constructed properly. I notice in your plot that the aesthetics are inputs instead of fields in the data. You might need `aes_string` instead of `aes` to use inputs like this.

Comment: That hasn't worked unfortunately

Comment: It looks like `input$DateRep` is a vector of two dates. What are you trying to put as the aesthetic in the plot? You are giving it two string dates...

Comment: likewise, `input$Cases` is a numeric value. aesthetics need to be columns in your data set.

Comment: The plot should display a geom plot with the date on x axis, cases on y axis, geom size id deaths and color is country

Comment: dude, there's problems everywhere in this script. It doesn't even run as is. You have no options to choose from under your country checkboxgroupinput

Comment: @cory you should remove "include" in `checkboxGroupInput`, I have edited this post

Comment: @bretauv thanks - but this has not solved the question

Comment: indeed, you have problem with `checkboxGroupInput` and actually, I think you should prefer `selectInput` (you don't want a box per country). First, replace `checkboxGroupInput(...)` by ```selectInput("Country", "Select Country", choices = unique(data$`Countries and territories`), selected = "Afghanistan")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to define and filter the data you want to plot in a `reactive` expression outside of `renderPlot`. It will allow you to re-use these data more easily and it is easier (from my point of view) to use `ggplot` without inputs directly in it.

I include `as.Date(DateRep) >= input$DateRep[1] & as.Date(DateRep) <= input$DateRep[2])` in `filter` to select the interval between the two chosen dates. Since the column `DateRep` has a `POSIXct` format, you need to use `as.Date` on it to convert it to the format `dateRangeInput` produces.

Here's the result:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), ".xlsx", sep = "")

GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))

data <- read_excel(tf)

include<-c("United_Kingdom","Italy","France","China",
           "United_States_of_America","Spain","Germany",
           "Iran","South_Korea","Switzerland")
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("COVID-19 Daily Confirmed Cases & Deaths"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("Country", "Select Country", choices = include, selected = "France"),
      dateRangeInput("DateRep","Select Date Range", start = "2019-12-31", end = NULL),
      sliderInput("Cases","Select Cases Range", min = 1, max = 20000, value = NULL),
      sliderInput("Deaths", "Select Death Range", min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100),
      submitButton("Refresh")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  plot_data <- reactive({
    filter(data, `Countries and territories` %in% input$Country 
           & as.Date(DateRep) >= input$DateRep[1]
           & as.Date(DateRep) <= input$DateRep[2]) %>%
       filter(between(Cases, 1, input$Cases))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot_data() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(DateRep), y= Cases, size = Deaths, color = `Countries and territories`)) +
      geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
      theme_light()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I started to fix this, but ran out of time... so here's what I did, maybe you can complete it...

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), ".xlsx", sep = "")

GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))

data <- read_excel(tf)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("COVID-19 Daily Confirmed Cases & Deaths"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("country_checkbox"),
      dateRangeInput("DateRep","Select Date Range", start = "2019-12-31", end = NULL),
      sliderInput("Cases","Select Cases Range", min = 1, max = 20000, value = NULL),
      sliderInput("Deaths", "Select Death Range", min = 1, max = 10000, value = 100)
      #submitButton("Refresh")


    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$country_checkbox <- renderUI({
    countries <- unique(data.frame(data)[, "Countries.and.territories"])
    checkboxGroupInput("country", "Select Country", 
                       choices = countries,
                       selected = NULL, inline = FALSE,
                       width = NULL)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    include<-input$country

    plot_data<-filter(data, `Countries and territories` %in% include)%>%
      filter(between(Cases, 1, input$Cases))

    plot_data%>% ggplot(aes(x=DateRep, y=Cases, size =Deaths, color = `Countries and territories`)) +
      geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
      theme_light()

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```